# Prevent SBS 2008  from connecting to an iomega-storage via DCOM

Tags: windows-sbs-2008, dcom

I have one Windows Small Business Server 2008 with his system-event-log flooded with eventid 10009 and source DCOM.
DCOM works perfectly with every single machine in the network except the iomega storage.
I don't know if the iomega storage should be able to process DCOM requests, but if not, there must be any way to prevent SBS 2008 from contacting the storage via DCOM.

Any ideas or clarifications?

**Update**:

The iomega-storage is part of the Domain (it's added to Domain-Computers in AD). 
I would really like to eliminate that error. I'd be thankfull for each hint that leads me to the right direction.